# When i press run flutter it is show "Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project. :"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When I press run flutter it is show

`Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.`

the Error image
[image]

flutter doctor
[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Close your terminal and open again

Comment: it is show  same eror

Comment: check if you have select the main file in run section

Comment: your pubspec file is inside `/ua/ali` not `/ua`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ua` is not the correct directory for your project. You need to change your working directory with:

```
 cd ali
```

Then, you can `flutter run`.